# Mysql , join a table and have multiple conditions from different rows

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables , one emails: id,email and one meteemails: id,eid(id from emails),field_name,field_info)

ill give an example : on metaemails i have for some emails : field_name="source", field_info="uk"; field_name="status", field_value="active".

i want to query for all emails that have those fields in metaemails.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can add multiple condition for join via `AND`. Where is problem?

Comment: my query was something like this:  ->join('metaemails','emails.id', '=', 'metaemails.eid')
          ->select('emails.*')
                ->where('metaemails.field_name', '=', 'source')
                ->where('metaemails.field_info', '=', 'uk')
                ->where('metaemails.field_name', '=', 'status')
                ->where('metaemails.field_info', '=', 'active')   . And i get 0 results.

Comment: if i cut from that query the last two where , i mean to query only for field_name ='source' and 'field_info'='uk' i get results and same, i get results if i query for field_name='status' and field_info='active'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit trickier than it seems, you can't just join the two tables and put two `WHERE` conditions: if you do something like

```
WHERE field_name = 'source' AND field_info = 'uk'
AND field_name = 'status' AND field_info = 'active'
```

you are always going to get zero results because that condition is always false, since the same field cannot have two different values.

One way to get the information you need is this: do a JOIN for each meta value you need.
For example, the query:

```
SELECT e.id, mesrc.field_value source, mesta.field_info status
FROM emails e
JOIN metaemails mesrc ON e.id = mesrc.eid AND mesrc.field_name = 'source'
JOIN metaemails mesta ON e.id = mesta.eid AND mesta.field_name = 'status';
```

will give you something like this:

```
id  source  status
1   uk      active
2   fr      active
3   uk      inactive
```

I made up the data, of course (you can see what I did [here](http://rextester.com/IYHYQ22704)). Basically, we are joining the first time to associate every email with a "source" meta, and the second time to associate it with a "status" meta. Now you can actually use the `WHERE` conditions you need, like:

```
SELECT e.id, mesrc.field_value source, mesta.field_info status
FROM emails e
JOIN metaemails mesrc ON e.id = mesrc.eid AND mesrc.field_name = 'source'
JOIN metaemails mesta ON e.id = mesta.eid AND mesta.field_name = 'status'
WHERE mesrc.field_info = 'uk'
AND mesta.field_info = 'active';
```

Comment: Thanks alot, now it makes sense.